# Backslash in URL path changing path to public

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, path, directory, mean-stack

I have my stylesheets linked in my header as

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meanmenu.min.css">
```

I'm using the MEAN stack in AWS Cloud9 Development Environment, and when I preview my application, everything is styled exactly how I plan using these stylesheets as they're in my public directory, but when I add any backslash into the end of my URL path in preview the stylesheets are not linking. For example, stylesheets are clearly linked on mysite.com/test, but mysite.com/test/ or mysite.com/test/example seems to unlink and everything is in standard raw HTML format. If I link the CDN they work, but I need to link custom stylesheets as well.

I have

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

to tell the browser where to search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the next level after test (eg: mysite.com/test/example), you need to go up a level, since paths are relative.

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/meanmenu.min.css">
```

Now, hardcoding your paths might get annoying after a while; you might want to provide these paths as part of your locals.

Comment: Yes, that's so obvious. I don't know why I wasn't making that connection. Thanks!